# Is Tetris a packing or covering problem?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, packing-problem

I am looking for some information about packing and covering problems. Some texts mention Tetris without further elaboration. Now, I am wondering if Tetris is a kind of packing or covering problem.

According to Wikipedia,

> packing : '*... involve attempting to pack objects together into
>   containers*'
>
> covering : '*... how many of the same objects are required to
>   completely cover every region of the container*'

Let us consider the situation that *given $n$ tetrominoes, we opt to find as many gap-free rows as possible*. (Thanks @Newb for pointing this out.) On one hand, when playing Tetris, I would like to pack the tetrominoes as densely as possible so that no holes appear in a row. On the other hand, we are covering the rectangular 'board' with tetrominoes. Which interpretation is correct?

I would also like to take this opportunity to ask for reference for packing and covering problems for those who are new to this area. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Tetris" is a game. You need to be more specific about the *problem* you mean. For example: given $n$ tetrominoes, can we fit them in a $i \times j$ board?

Unless you clearly define the problem you mean, Tetris could be anything.

Comment: @Newb : What about this: given $n$ tetrominoes, at most how many gap-free rows can be produced?

Comment: good stuff. You should make that your question.

Comment: It's an "exact cover" problem, sometimes called a tiling problem. If you want to read into how to solve these optimally, look into Algorithm X, and Dancing Links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not a packing problem. Packing problems are usually in the context of geometry -- how many hexagons can I pack in this circle? How many tetrahedra can I pack in this sphere? i.e. usually involve continuous areas/volumes.

Tetris, on the other hand, is totally discrete: one block per square! There's no area/volume manoeuvring to be done here. In fact, we can represent the Tetris game as a graph with $200$ nodes (the Tetris board traditionally has dimensions $20 \times 10$). When we view the board like this, then I think this is reasonably close to the class of graph covering problems.

It may not be a covering problem in the traditional sense (we usually talk about [minimal vertex covers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover)), but it's definitely close enough to call your problem a covering problem, rather than a packing problem.

(By the way, to further convince yourself, I suggest reading the introduction of [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) on packing. The 'container' in your problem is very much unlike the containers of traditional packing problems.)